# showing result from database in selectManyListbox

Tags: jsp, jsf, selectmanylistbox

I am creating a JSF app. The datatype of a column is `set(a,b,c)` in MySQL.
Each row has some options like `a,c` or `a,b`, etc. I have a listbox in my app with a,b,c as available items and the user has option to select multiple items.

When I edit the entry in MySQL, I need to populate the listbox with values from DB. How can I do that?

Comment: Just wondering, are you really using legacy JSP? Not Facelets?

Answer (score 0):

Just set the property which you've bound to its `value` attribute the usual way in bean's (post)constructor.

E.g.

```
<h:selectManyListbox value="#{bean.selectedItems}">
    <f:selectItems value="#{bean.availableItems}" />
</h:selectManyListbox>
```

with

```
private List<String> selectedItems; // +getter+setter
private List<String> availableItems; // +getter

@PostConstruct
public void init() { 
    selectedItems = getItFromDatabase(); // <--- Look here. Just preset it.
    availableItems = Arrays.asList("a", "b", "c");
}
```

#### See also:

- [Our `selectOneMenu` wiki page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/selectonemenu/info)

Comment: I need to override the init method? I am doing stuff in bean, and bean is POJO